# COLLATION 'utf8_unicode_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'latin1'

Tags: php, mysql, zend-db, mysql-proxy

I've had a look at the other answers, and none of them solve this.

We have a website running through mysql-proxy to the 2 mariadb servers.

all the tables are encoded using utf8_unicode_ci, but when the web-app tries to do a query, it throws this error.

I am thinking its something to do with the connection charset, but no idea where its coming from.

We are using Symfony2 with ZendDB, which is setting the charset as utf8.

Im totally lost, please help!

Comment: SELECT common_schema.extract_json_value(tagData,'runId') as theRunId, `communicationsLog`.* FROM `communicationsLog` HAVING `theRunId` = '2' ORDER BY `sent` DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0

Comment: No, fixed it. SELECT common_schema.extract_json_value(tagData,'runId') as theRunId, `communicationsLog`.* FROM `communicationsLog` HAVING `theRunId` = '2' COLLATE utf8_general_ci ORDER BY `sent` DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;

Comment: If that fixed your problem, then it's a bug in MySQL.  What version are you using?

Comment: extract_json_value is part of the mysql common_schema plugin. https://code.google.com/p/common-schema/

Comment: Its MariaDB 10 im sure.